# implement callback in function

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a function which draws different popups depending on the value of my monitor type. If my `monitorType = 22` I need to send an ajax request and depending on the response continue the drawing. But the problem is that I cant get response before to continue.
Here is that part of my function:

```
var str = '<div id="thresholdsHeader" style="display:none;">';
            str += '<div id="alertRule"></div>';
            if(monitorTypeId == 22 ){                   
            var parametrs = {
                    monitorId: module.info.id,
                    typeId: module.info.monitorTypeId
                    };
                sendGetAPIRequest(Framework.customMonitorURL, "getMonitorDynamicMetrics", parametrs, ThresholdManager.getDynamicThresholdsRequest);             
                if(dynResponse.json.length == 0){
                    str += '<input type="button" designstyle="green" onclick="ThresholdManager.addThresholdDialog()" style="float:right;" value="'+Framework.Lang.addThreshold+'"/>';
                }else{
                    str +=  '<input type="button" id="trehsoldsGreenBut" designstyle="green" onclick="ThresholdManager.createThresholds(event)" style="float:right;" value="'+Framework.Lang.addThreshold+'"/><div class="dashboardIcons addNewRuleArrow" style="left: '+(CURRENT_LANGUAGE == 'en'? '460':(CURRENT_LANGUAGE == 'de'?'363':'355'))+'px;top: 8px;"></div>';
                }                   
            }else   {
                    str += '<input type="button" designstyle="green" onclick="ThresholdManager.addThresholdDialog()" style="float:right;" value="'+Framework.Lang.addThreshold+'"/>';
            }
            str += '</div><div id="thresholdContainer"></div>';
```

and this is my request handler :

```
 getDynamicThresholdsRequest: function(response){
            dynResponse = response;
     },
```

if I go slow by debugging it works ok.

Comment: whats the content of **sendGetAPIRequest** .. Cant you add a callback function as an additional parameter?

Comment: thanks @Andreas, it is interesting, but I could not use it in my case. Im new in js

Answer (score 0):

Can you try like as follow:-

```
  var str = '<div id="thresholdsHeader" style="display:none;">';
            str += '<div id="alertRule"></div>';
            if(monitorTypeId == 22 ){                   
            var parametrs = {
                    monitorId: module.info.id,
                    typeId: module.info.monitorTypeId
                    };
                sendGetAPIRequest(Framework.customMonitorURL, "getMonitorDynamicMetrics", parametrs, ThresholdManager.getDynamicThresholdsRequest);    
           setTimeout( function(){        
                if(dynResponse.json.length == 0){
                    str += '<input type="button" designstyle="green" onclick="ThresholdManager.addThresholdDialog()" style="float:right;" value="'+Framework.Lang.addThreshold+'"/>';
                }else{
                    str +=  '<input type="button" id="trehsoldsGreenBut" designstyle="green" onclick="ThresholdManager.createThresholds(event)" style="float:right;" value="'+Framework.Lang.addThreshold+'"/><div class="dashboardIcons addNewRuleArrow" style="left: '+(CURRENT_LANGUAGE == 'en'? '460':(CURRENT_LANGUAGE == 'de'?'363':'355'))+'px;top: 8px;"></div>';
                }                   
            }else   {
                    str += '<input type="button" designstyle="green" onclick="ThresholdManager.addThresholdDialog()" style="float:right;" value="'+Framework.Lang.addThreshold+'"/>';
            }
            str += '</div><div id="thresholdContainer"></div>';},3000)
```

Use

> SetTimeOut function

and give delay for execution.

Answer (score 0):

are you using jquery or something similar?

If not, what I would suggest it re-organising your code flow.

PS: I am doing a wild attempt with the finite information you have given.

```
sendGetAPIRequest(Framework.customMonitorURL, "getMonitorDynamicMetrics", parametrs, ThresholdManager.getDynamicThresholdsRequest, function(resp) {
   //add all the logic to be added on response here
});
```